# Create an Handler function to generate randomly 5 coordinates

Tags: android

Good morning, I need help with this function, I do not understand how the handler works.
This is my current code:

public class GeneraMarker {

```
static LatLng GenPosition(Double Lat, Double Long) {
    final Handler gen = new Handler();
    Runnable gener = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (counter) {
                  //Random coordinates generator
            } else {
                gen.removeCallbacks(null);
                gen.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

            }

            gen.postDelayed(this, 600000);

        }

    };
    gen.post(gener);


    return aPosition;
}
```

}

Comment: Counter for 5 times*

Comment: is your "aPosition" is always null? if not what's wrong with this. can you explain.

Comment: aPosition should be generated coordinates, but IDE tells me that handler is wrong whit this message: "Handler" is abstract; can not be istantiated, but i do not understand the problem! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Handler` receive a `Runnable` object, to run block of code. and its execution is separate from your method execution. so you have to create a listener to listen your generated `latlang` Like given below

```
 static void GenPosition(Double Lat, Double Long,ListenerClass listener) {
final Handler gen = new Handler();
Runnable gener = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (counter) {
              //Random coordinates generator
         listener.generatedLatLang(newLatLang);
        } else {
            gen.removeCallbacks(null);
            gen.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

        }

        gen.postDelayed(this, 600000);

    }

};
gen.post(gener);
}
```